# intelliJ 14.14 Community Ed Scala plugin does not recognize package hierarchy

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14

I'm having a peculiar issue with a intelliJ Scala project of mine. As you can see in the attached picture, despite the fact that the Scala compiler is not complaining about my import of class `AtomicTest`, it somehow expects `atomicscala` to be an object instead of a (sub-)package. What gives?

[image: A picture of my intelliJ project]

Comment: From what I can see, the project structure is not correct. Most importantly you do not have any folders marked as *source* folders. How did you create/import/open this project?

Comment: I have dictated the "examples" folder as my root source folder, instead of the default "src", which I deleted. I already had the sources in this exact structure, and created a new intelliJ project on top. Initially, this created an empty "src" folder as the root source folder, yet this altered the underlying Git information, and I did not want that: I simply want all my packages, sub-packages, as well as some Scala scripts and class files, to lie underneath the root source folder which, in this case, is "examples".

Comment: Looks like the file `AtomicTest.class` is not a Scala source file, but a JVM bytecode/class file. Try putting this into a library folder that you add as a dependency. - Also, in which package is the `AtomicTest` class, anyway? Could it be that it was compiled to be in another package?

Comment: @madoc Nah, I ran `scalac` again to make sure that the package in `AtomicTest.scala` was correct and the bytecode file was sent to the appropriate sub-package. I just solved the problem by re-creating the project from scratch, see my answer. But thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem after creating an SBT project from scratch. Instead of creating a new project or importing a project from the startup screen, I clicked on "open" and followed through from there. Can't really vouch as to what it was that enabled the compiler to view imports without error, but at least it works.